# FireStore Collection Group Under Specific Collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've read into the `collectionGroup` docs and have read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68049541/collectiongroupquery-but-limit-search-to-subcollections-under-a-particular-docum/68049847#68049847) on getting collections from a specific document.

I'm looking for something similar, but where I list all of the sub collections that are referenced by documents within a specific collection.

For example, my ideal query would be something like `db.collection('metrics').collectionGroup('days')`, where `metrics` is the large collection that contains documents, each of which have a sub collection `days`.

Comment: I'm also going to tie this question to this [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56934947/collectiongroup-within-a-certain-path) that discusses the same problem where they suggest adding the parent collection's name as a field in each document under the `/days` collections.

Comment: I also think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-query-collections-in-firestore-under-a-certain-path-6a0d686cebd2) will help.

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of [the answer you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68049847/3068190). I looked into [the guard](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/2e6d95a0851304a9b7c069f55e5c8fb817a5e3cc/packages/firestore/src/lite/query.ts#L697-L704) that prevented me from expanding that answer to cover both documents and collections. It is unfortunately [still in place](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/c8a6e08b01a52b3eca77ca9da8989dac2e77a972/packages/firestore/src/lite-api/query.ts#L968-L976) as of `firebase` v9.17.1.

As long as that guard remains in place, collection group queries may only search the whole database or be restricted to paths that fall under a particular **document**. A collection is not currently possible.

The workaround for this would be to nest the `metrics` collection under its own document. For the sake of efficiency, you will want to keep this collection ID and document ID as short as possible. In the example below, I have used 'g' as shorthand for 'group' and '1' to indicate 'group 1' (could also use 'm' for metrics). Note: If you intend to have more than 10 such groups, start using `01`, `02`, etc. now, otherwise the below query will return invalid results.

```json
"/g": {
  "/1": {
    "/metrics": {
      "/docA": {
        "/days": { /* ... */ }
      },
      "/docB": {
        "/days": { /* ... */ }
      },
      "/docC": {
        "/days": { /* ... */ }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which would allow you to then restrict paths to that group using:

```js
// note: legacy syntax
firebase.firestore().collectionGroup('days')
  .orderBy(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId())
  .startAt("g/1"),
  .endAt("g/1\uf8ff")
  .get()
  .then((querySnapshot) => {
    console.log("Found " + querySnapshot.size + " docs");
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => console.log("> " + doc.ref.path))
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error("Failed to execute query", err);
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned getting collections under a document. This is a sub collections and the query is something like

`db.collection('metrics').document('x').collection('days')`

from this reference you can query the documents in the `days` sub collection under document `x`

`db.collectionGroup('days')`

this will query all documents in all days collections regardless of what document they are under.

Comment: Hi! I'm not interested in what document the collection is under, just that they are all in the 'metrics' collection. Ideally I want every doc in the metrics' collections sub collection as a collection group,

Comment: Sub collections are nested under documents. It is not possible to have a sub collection of another collection. to query all documents in a sub collection regardless of document that is a collectionGroup query.

Comment: If the issue is that maybe you have 'days' as a sub collection somewhere else but in this query you only want to query metrics/days as group, but you don't want somethingelse/days, then I believe the issue here is that you should have named those sub collections differently.